# Skip 2 lines after reading 1 line of a file using AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I have a huge file which i am reading through awk , using awk i am calculating the sum of values on that file.

Below is the file format i have :

```
18/11/13 00:00:50   585   17353  296883     666   
18/11/13 00:01:50   965   26536  216201     558   
18/11/13 00:02:50   990   38685  390537     768   
18/11/13 00:03:50  1004   22435  377633     404   
18/11/13 00:04:50   709   15754  161435   12062   
18/11/13 00:05:50    96    7084  403551       0   
18/11/13 00:06:50   107   14588  504683     597   
18/11/13 00:07:50   115   27562  457555     814   



awk  '{sum+=$4; ++n} END {print "  Tot="n," Avg="sum/n}' filename
```

Now i thin i want to skip 2 rows after we read a row from the file.

Comment: a)which two rows you want to skip? b) your file is not sorted, how is "highest increment" defined?

Comment: For a ) Read $4 value from first row and then skip 2 rows , then again read $4 from the 4th row like wise for all rows

Comment: For b) Disregard  that section once a is done i will handle that in an other way

Answer (score 0):

for your comment under your question, you just need to skip line2 and 3:

```
awk  'NR==1||NR>3{sum+=$4; ++n} END {print "  Tot="n," Avg="sum/n}' filename
```

Comment: it is always giving me first row

Comment: @Developer don't understand your comment. For your example, it outputs `Tot=6  Avg=17462.7` here.

Comment: if 4 lines are there it and if i am printing $0 then only 1st line is coming